# How to check memory consuming process on AWS RDS postgressql

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, rds

I am using `AWS RDS postgresql` with instance type `db.t2.medium` which has `4GB` of memory. In monitoring the RAM consumption is more than `3.3GB` continuously. How to determine which process is consuming the more memory. `Enhance monitoring` is also not there for postgresql. So can't determine why there is so much consumption of the memory.

Comment: Hi @ajeet khan, how are you monitoring the RAM consumption of the RDS instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to monitor or worry about RDS, Amazon monitors it for you. So long as performance meets your needs just leave it be.

It's probably being used by cache - either disk or database.

Comment: But if the usage increases and the memory gets utilized to its full capacity than it will affect the performance and may cause downtime.

Comment: Free memory is wasted memory. Memory is far better used for cache, it can be freed instantly if memory is needed for something more important. I would expect memory consumption to be close to 100%. I repeat my earlier advice - if your database is performing as expected then full memory is not an issue. Monitor your database performance, if it starts to drop then you can consider options.

Comment: Can you suggest ways to monitor database performance?

Comment: Yes, use Cloudwatch http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Monitoring.html